# Div background image not showing then display image alt text

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, image

This is my html code where I have one div and have one image outside div

```
<div runat="server" id="ProductThumbnail" style="width:140px;height:140px;position:relative;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;">                    
<asp:Image  ID="ProductThumbnail1" runat="server" Style="max-height: 50px;position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;" />
</div>
<asp:Image  ID="Imagealt" runat="server" />
```

what i am doing is i am setting div BACKGROUND image from server side as code

```
ProductThumbnail.Style.Add("BACKGROUND-IMAGE", "url(" + Item.ThumbnailUrl.Replace("~", "..") + ")");
```

What I want is in case if div background image url is not showing any image than in that case Imagealt will shows alt text which I set from back-end and in case if div background image url is showing image in that case Imagealt get hidden

**I want all this to be done on server side code and javascript**

Plaese review below image
[image]

**On left side div image is not there so the image alt text is showing that is correct but on right side image is displaying still down alt text is coming which is wrong

I don't want to show alt text if div background image is displayed**

**1-If image is there no alt text**

**2-If image is not displaying then show alt text**

**For example :**

If my div background image url path is set to this url

```
http://meenaprints.in/Admin/images/productimg/thumbnail/436x636_4736.jpg
```

than alt text should not come as this URL is retrieving image

BUT

If div background image URL path is set to URL

```
http://meenaprints.in/Admin/images/productimg/thumbnail/436x636_473123.jpg
```

which is not retrieving image than ALT text should get display

Comment: The image is not showing...can you inspect the div background to see where it is pointing(I think that a wrong path is passed)

Comment: The code written is correct i just need to find the code for which if dic background image is not there it shows alt text

Comment: So the code is correct...you don't have any problem...good :)

Comment: I need to code for when div shows image image alt text doesnot get display , if div image backdround image url is wrong so but obvious image will not get display, in that case i need image alt text to get display

Comment: @Hackerman please review updated question. hope u will get what i need

Comment: Do you mean just setting an image AltText ? like `<asp:Image  ID="ProductThumbnail1" runat="server" AlternateText="Image text" Style="max-height: 50px;position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;" />`

Comment: As u can see in image, if image is not displaying for pamper product it is displaying alt text that is good, but in case if image is displaying in div the alt text should not come, How can I check for div if i set URL/Google Url path for div background_image, and that path will display image for div

Comment: @DartFeld Please see updated question, I hope u will get for what i am asking for

Answer (score 0):

Why not check if the product image exists and show/hide the appropriate Images.

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("product.jpg")))
{
    ProductThumbnail1.Visible = true;
    Imagealt.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    ProductThumbnail1.Visible = false;
    Imagealt.Visible = true;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Then perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
<div id="imageContainer">
    <div id="altText">Alt text of image</div>
    <div id="imagePlaceHolder" style="display: none;">
        <img src="/test.png" onload="imageIsLoaded()" />
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function imageIsLoaded() {
        document.getElementById("altText").style.display = "none";
        //show the image
        document.getElementById("imagePlaceHolder").style.display = "block";
        //or set the image as background
        document.getElementById("imageContainer").style.background = "center center  no-repeat url('test.png')";
    }
</script>
```

Only when the image is loaded will `imageIsLoaded` be called and thus show the image and hide the alt text.

Comment: but in case if the GOOgle URL is coming in that case how can we search that this url has image and that image is loaded or not loaded in div background?

Comment: Please see updated question, I hope u will get for what i am asking for